# Using Header globally in react using react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am currently using `react-router-dom` to create navigation within my web app.

My index.js and App.js look like:

**Index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App />
        </Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**App.js**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Route exact path ='/' component={Home} />
          <Route path ='/container' component={Container} />
          <Route path ='/profile' component={ProfilePage} />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

I idea was that if `Home` contains the header and the sidebar, it would also keep it for other components like `Container` and `ProfilePage`.

My `Home`'s render looks like:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <div className="App">
          <Sidebar />
          <Container className="container-comp" />
          {this.renderLoggingOutput()}

        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

But when I Link to `/profile`, it just shows me the `ProfilePage` component without the header and the sidebar.

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your header outside the routes:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
       <Header /> <-------- place here or outside the routes at a minimum
        <div>
          <Route exact path ='/' component={Home} />
          <Route path ='/container' component={Container} />
          <Route path ='/profile' component={ProfilePage} />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

I have a similar structure in one of my apps.
the routes look like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
          <Navbar />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Dashboard}/>
            <Route path='/character/:id' component={CharacterDetails}/>
            <Route path='/encounter/:id' component={Encounter}/>
.........
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

The only job of a route is to mount a component. If you want omnipresent components across all routes, treat the routes as `children` to a base component.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Sidebar />
      {this.props.children}
    </div>
  }
}

const Routes = () => (
  <App>
    {/* your routes here */}
  </App>
)
```

Comment: Do we put `{this.Routes}` or `this.props.children`? Cuz the `this.props.children` doesn't actually use `Routes`

Comment: You would put `this.props.children`. `this.props.children` is a special prop in react.  With `this.props.children`, whatever you put in between `<App>` in the `Routes` will show up where `this.props.children` is in your `App` component. You can read more about it in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#propschildren).